# on-heap eviction in apache ignite

Tags: ignite

In Apache Ignote, when an entry is evicted from an on-heap cache, is it placed in the off-heap region?

From the docs, it doesn't seem so but looking for a clarification.

> The on-heap eviction policies remove the cache entries from Java heap only. The entries stored in the off-heap region of the memory are not affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Ignite 2.x, entries are always stored in off-heap memory and on-heap option allows enabling a lookup on-heap cache for the off-heap entries. When an entry is evicted from on-heap cache there is always a backing off-heap counterpart.

Ignite before 2.x uses different memory [modes](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.9/docs/off-heap-memory#section-tiered-off-heap-storage) and eviction behavior differs depending on it.